# How to call functional child component method from class parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a class based parent component like below

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import FunChild from "./FunChild";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.childRef = React.createRef();
    this.parentmethodFun = this.parentmethodFun.bind(this);
  }

  parentmethodFun() {
    this.childRef.current.childmethod();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FunChild />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.parentmethodFun}>
          function
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

the `funChild.js` file

```
import React from "react";

function FunChild(props) {
  childmethod() {
    console.log("child method is called");
  }

  return (<div>This is child ...!</div>);
}

export default FunChild;
```

if that child was a class component I can very easily use `ref={this.childRef}` to access child method.

But, it's a functional component and It was giving lot of problems. Can anyone please help me on this.

reference project link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-74xzn?file=/index.js

Comment: You could set a variable in your parent state, and pass setState by props to childs

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid this kind of relation because it is not the way how react works. In React you should pass everything from up to bottom. But if you reale want to achieve something like this you can use reference forwarding and [imperative handler hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle). E.g:

```
import { Component, forwardRef, createRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    childMethod() {
      console.log("child method is called");
    }
  }));

  return <div>This is child ...!</div>;
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.childRef = createRef();
    this.parentmethodFun = this.parentmethodFun.bind(this);
  }

  parentmethodFun() {
    this.childRef.childMethod();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={(ref) => (this.childRef = ref)} />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.parentmethodFun}>
          function
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Personally, i think you should rethink your application structure as it is very likely that there is a better solution than this trick.

Comment: I'm not using this. Just for learning purpose I asked it !

Comment: I'm getting child already defined error. can you please check this whether it is working or not ?

Comment: I have made a project here. Please check it ! https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-74xzn?file=/index.js

Comment: There is no error which you describee in this sandbox

Comment: That was not saved i think. but your code was not working. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-bxxlj?file=/Child.js

Comment: Inside index.js you create ```Child``` component and also import ```Child``` from other file. Alsoe there is problem with ```Child``` in index.js because you didn't import ```forwardRef``` from React and not return anything from there.